# What is the intuitive meaning of star and box in a pure type system?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus, ct.category-theory, intuition

The systems of the λ-cube have the axiom $\star:\square$.

I've listed a few meanings that the Curry-Howard isomorphism gives to $t : T$ below.  What are the intuitive meanings of $\star$ and $\square$ in each interpretation?

$t : T : \star : \square$

**Programs:** t is a program of type T.  (Possibility: T is a program of type $\star$?)

**Proofs:** t is a proof of theorem T.  It's hard to see T as a proof of $\star$, though.

**Set elements:** t is a member of set T.  (Possibility: T is a member of the universe $\star$ of sets.  Then it seems difficult to assign a meaning to $\square$ that avoids the membership $\square : \star$.)

I'd like to fill out this table both vertically and horizontally, with both further interpretations and the missing descriptions of $\star$ and $\square$, and possibly meanings of $T : \square$ for $T \neq \star$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\star$ is a *kind*, which classifies *types*.  $\square$ is a sort, and it classifies *kinds*.  So this is a 4-layer deep classification.  Once you get to have type-constructors, kinds get really useful.  Eventually, you wish for kind-constructors too, and then you need sorts.

Turns out that you really rarely ever need to get deeper than that (even though Coq and Agda have infinitely many such levels).  I am not sure I have ever read a good Curry-Howard explanation of kinds and sorts.  I would hazard a guess that classical mathematics rarely worries about kinds/sorts, I would tend to dig into $n$-categories to find a good relation.

Comment: Then for the "Programs" interpretation we have: t is a program of type T classified by * classified by square.  I was hoping that the relationships would stay the same within a given interpretation: if we say that t is a program of type T, then it seems that T should be some kind of program of type *.  Then perhaps * is the type of type-checking programs?

Comment: Yes, T is some kind of program of type *, but usually the type language is not Turing-complete, so the type-level programs are not so complicated.  That's not true when you have dependent types, like some of the systems in the lambda cube.

Answer (score 5):

I seem to recall there’s a really good explanation of kinds and sorts in Sørensen and Urzyczyn’s [Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444520775) (a previous version is available [online](http://folli.loria.fr/cds/1999/library/pdf/curry-howard.pdf)).

Comment: In any case, that's an excellent recommendation - that is a splendid set of 'lectures'.

Comment: There's a lot of material in the published book that are not in the online lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

I've found you won't go far wrong if you think of the objects in * as sets, and the objects in $\Box$ as proper classes.  Thus, * is the proper class of all sets.

Answer (score 0):

I found J. W. Roorda's masters thesis to be a good exposition of PTS.  It is linked from here:

http://people.cs.uu.nl/johanj/MSc/jwroorda/